# Kibana on AWS user management: Created new user but can't see my index patterns

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, kibana

I have a public provisioned Elasticsearch endpoint created on AWS. This gets me a public Kibana login endpoint. I got a default master username with it and a password. I can login, I created an index pattern, and I can see my data.

So far so good.

Now I wanted to give some users access. I created a couple of new users. Then in the user management section, gave them roles `all_access`, in the hope they should be able to see everything.

They can login, but instead of using my already created index pattern, they are prompted to create a new one.

Is that how it works? Do they need to create their own index pattern? Can't they just re-use my already created index pattern and directly go to `discover` and query the data?

Obviously, I am a newbie with `Kibana` and `ES`.

Comment: I'm not an expert at this either, but I think you need to consider that each user starts in their own private tenant and need to either create a new one or switch to the global tenant.

Comment: Yes indeed, I had figured that out as well myself but forgot to update. If you want to provide this as the answer I will be happy to accept it.

Comment: Just a note for anyone hunting that this applies to OpenSearch and AWS OpenSearch too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that Kibana tracks index patterns within **tenants**.  When users log in, they default into their private tenant.  In order to have shared index patterns they need to exist in the Global tenant or else in a custom tenant.  Additionally, the user will need to switch into the shared/public tenant where the objects exist.

Comment: so how does one go about fixing this in practice?